# How create list of Android Contacts with xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-contacts

How create list (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber) ?

My code created only FirstName and LastName.

```
 public List<PersonContact> GetPhoneContacts()
    {
        _phoneContacts = new List<PersonContact>();
        PhoneContacts = new List<PersonContact>();
        var ctx = Forms.Context;
        var contactList = new List<string>();
        var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;
        string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName };
        var cursor = ctx.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                contactList.Add(cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])));
            }
            while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }
        var sortedList = contactList.Where(s => s.Contains(" "));

        foreach (var cont in sortedList)
        {
            string[] words = cont.Split(' ');
            PersonContact contact = new PersonContact();
            contact.FirstName = words[0];
            contact.LastName = words[1];
            _phoneContacts.Add(contact);
        }
        PhoneContacts = _phoneContacts;
        return PhoneContacts;
    }
```

I take for example one element of list "Kate Parry" and Split this string.

My main problem is that come 2000 email addresses. Find ' ' and filtered.

Comment: So, let me clarify if I got it right. You need First, Last Name and phone number? From what I see you decide if person has first or last name using Split space? What if person has only first name, do you want filter him out? And you are missing phone number at all. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public List<PersonContact> GetPhoneContacts()
    {
        var phoneContacts = new List<PersonContact>();

        using (var phones = ApplicationContext.ContentResolver.Query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            if (phones != null)
            {
                while (phones.MoveToNext())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string name = phones.GetString(phones.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName));
                        string phoneNumber = phones.GetString(phones.GetColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));

                        string[] words = name.Split(' ');
                        PersonContact contact = new PersonContact();
                        contact.FirstName = words[0];
                        if (words.Length > 1)
                            contact.LastName = words[1];
                        else
                            contact.LastName = ""; //no last name, is that ok?
                        contact.PhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                        phoneContacts.Add(contact);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //something wrong with one contact, may be display name is completely empty, decide what to do
                    }
                }
                phones.Close(); //not really neccessary, we have "using" above
            }
            //else we cannot get to phones, decide what to do
        }

        return phoneContacts;
    }


public class PersonContact
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: good work! but if user create phone contact with only LastName? How to get contact.LastName other way? And please unification code (if phone contact without phoneNumber). I want to get all list contacts (with phoneNumbers and without). Sorry for my English+))

Comment: Don't you think that you can go from here yourself? :-)